# How does Huggingface's zero-shot classification work in production/webapp, do I need to train the model first?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, text-classification, large-language-model, zeroshot-classification

I have already used huggingface's zero-shot classification: I used "facebook/bart-large-mnli" model as reported here (https://huggingface.co/tasks/zero-shot-classification). The  accuracy is quite good for my task.

- My question is about productionizing the code: In particular I would like to create a Gradio (or streamlit) webapp. Do I need to train the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" model  first, secondly save the model in a pickle file, and then predict a new (unseen) sentence using the pickle file?
- Or can I simply import the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" library and compute the prediction for the production/webapp code?

The latter scenario would be preferable. But I am not sure whether loading the model from scratch would produce the same output as loadingthe pickle file with the saved facebook/bart-large-mnli" model.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no need to train anything when the accuracy is good. You also don't need to pickle it. You can just go with the second scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Q: How does zero-shot classification work? Do I need train/tune the model to use in production?

Options:

- (i) train the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" model first, secondly save the model in a pickle file, and then predict a new (unseen) sentence using the pickle file? or
- (ii) can I simply import the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" library and compute the prediction for the production/webapp code?

A (human): (ii) You can load up the model with `pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")` once when the server start, then reuse the pipeline **without** re-initializing it for each request.

When you use the model off-the-shelf, it'll be zero-shot but if you fine-tune a model with limited training data, people commonly refer to that as "few-shot"; take a look at https://github.com/huggingface/setfit for few-shot learning.

---

The proof is in the pudding, see if the model you pick fits the task you want. Also, there's more than one way to wield the shiny hammer =)

**Disclaimer:** Your Miles May Vary...

### Zero shot classification

**TL;DR:** I don't want to train anything, I don't have labeled data, do something with some labels that I come up with.

```
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")

text = "Catan (Base Game) | Ages 10+ | for 3 to 4 Players | Average Playtime 60 Minutes | Made by Catan Studio | TRADE, BUILD AND SETTLE: Embark on a quest to settle the isle of Catan! Guide your settlers to victory by clever trading and cunning development. But beware! Someone might cut off your road or buy a monopoly. And you never know when the wily robber might steal some of your precious games!"

candidate_labels = ['Beauty & Wellness', 'Electronics', 'Toys & Games']

classifier(text, candidate_labels)
```

[out]:

```
{'sequence': 'Catan (Base Game) | Ages 10+ | for 3 to 4 Players | Average Playtime 60 Minutes | Made by Catan Studio | TRADE, BUILD AND SETTLE: Embark on a quest to settle the isle of Catan! Guide your settlers to victory by clever trading and cunning development. But beware! Someone might cut off your road or buy a monopoly. And you never know when the wily robber might steal some of your precious games!',
 'labels': ['Toys & Games', 'Electronics', 'Beauty & Wellness'],
 'scores': [0.511284351348877, 0.38416239619255066, 0.10455326735973358]}
```

### Don't classify, translate (or seq2seq)

Inspiration: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05774

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model_name = "google/flan-t5-large"

tokenizer= AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

text = "Catan (Base Game) | Ages 10+ | for 3 to 4 Players | Average Playtime 60 Minutes | Made by Catan Studio | TRADE, BUILD AND SETTLE: Embark on a quest to settle the isle of Catan! Guide your settlers to victory by clever trading and cunning development. But beware! Someone might cut off your road or buy a monopoly. And you never know when the wily robber might steal some of your precious games!"


prompt=f"""Which category is this product?
QUERY:{text}
OPTIONS:
 - Beauty & Wellness
 - Electronics
 - Toys & Games
"""

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

tokenizer.decode(model.generate(input_ids)[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
```

[out]:

```
Toys & Games
```

And for the fun of it =)

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model_name = "google/flan-t5-large"

tokenizer= AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

prompt=f"""How does zero-shot classification work? 
QUERY: Do I need tune/modify the model to use in production?
OPTIONS:
 - (i) train the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" model first, secondly save the model in a pickle file, and then predict a new (unseen) sentence using the pickle file
 - (ii) can I simply import the "facebook/bart-large-mnli" library and compute the prediction for the production/webapp code
"""

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

print(tokenizer.decode(model.generate(input_ids)[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

[out]:

```
(ii)
```

---

### Q: What if both methods above don't work?

A: Try more models from https://huggingface.co/models or try different tasks and be creative in how to use what's available to fit your data to solve the problem

## Q: What if none of the models/tasks works?

A: Then it's time to think about what data you can/need to collect to train the model you need. But before collecting the data, it'll be prudent to first decide how you want to evaluate/measure the success of the model, e.g. F1-score, accuracy, etc.

This is how I'll personally solve NLP problems that fits the frame "X problem, Y approach" solutions, https://hackernoon.com/what-kind-of-scientist-are-you (shameless plug)

## Q: How do I deploy a model after I found the model+task I want?

There're several ways but it'll be out-of-scope of this question, since it's asking about how zero-shot works and more pertinently "Can I use zero-shot classification models off-the-shelf without training?".

To deploy a model, take a look at:

- https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/hugging-face-on-azure/
- https://huggingface.co/inference-endpoints

Comment: Once I finetuned a zero-shot Facebook model with my own labeled data, how will I be able to test it? I have a test dataset but I'm not sure how to evaluate my finetuned model with it.